# Making code using JavaScript for dependent selects RESTful

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

Ruby 2.0.0, Rails 4.0.3, Windows 8.1 Update, PostgreSQL 9.3.3

I have code that uses JavaScript to power dependent selects.  To do so, it references a controller method that retrieves the data for the following select.  I'm told that, because that method is non-standard, this is not RESTful.

I understand that REST is a set of specific constraints regarding client/server communications.  I've read some information about it but certainly don't have in-depth knowledge.  I am curious about the impact and resolution.  So, regarding the question about my configuration and REST:  First, would that be accurate that it is not RESTful?  Second, how does that impact my application?  Third, what should/could I do to resolve that?  Providing one example:

The route is:  (probably the concern?)

```
post 'cars/make_list', to: 'cars#make_list'
```

This is the first select:   (OBTW, I use ERB but removed less than/percent)

```
= f.input(:ymm_year_id, {input_html: {form: 'edit_car', car: @car, value: @car.year}, collection: YmmYear.all.order("year desc").collect { |c| [c.year, c.id] }, prompt: "Year?"})
```

This is the dependent select:

```
= render partial: "makes", locals: {form: 'edit_car', car: @car}
```

This is the partial:

```
= simple_form_for car,
                    defaults: {label: false},
                    remote: true do |f|
     makes ||= "" 
     make    = "" 
     make = car.make_id if car.class == Car and Car.exists?(car.id) 
     if !makes.blank? 
        = f.input :ymm_make_id, {input_html: {form: form, car: car, value: make}, collection: makes.collect { |s| [s.make, s.id] }, prompt: "Make?"} 
     else 
        = f.input :ymm_make_id, {input_html: {form: form, car: car, value: make}, collection: [], prompt: "Make?"} 
     end 
 end
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   ...  
    // when the #year field changes
    $("#car_ymm_year_id").change(function () {
        var year = $('select#car_ymm_year_id :selected').val();
        var form = $('select#car_ymm_year_id').attr("form");
        var car  = $('select#car_ymm_year_id').attr("car");
        $.post('/cars/make_list/',
            {
                form: form,
                year: year,
                car: car
            },
            function (data) {
                $("#car_ymm_make_id").html(data);
            });
        return false;
    });
    ...
});
```

And the method:

```
  def make_list
    makes = params[:year].blank? ? "" : YmmMake.where(ymm_year_id: params[:year]).order(:make)
    render partial: "makes", locals: {car: params[:car], form: params[:form], makes: makes}
  end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I had to describe if, being RESTful means that:

1. You provide meaningful resources names
2. You use the HTTP verbs to express your intents
3. You make proper use of HTTP codes to indicate status

**Provide meaningful resource names**

As you probably heard it before, everything in REST is about resources. But from the outside, it's just the paths you expose. Your resources are then just a bunch of paths such as:

```
GET /burgers # a collection of burgers

GET /burger/123 # a burger identified with id 123

GET /burger/123/nutrition_facts # the nutrition facts of burger 123

POST /burgers # with data: {name: "humble jack", ingredients: [...]} to create a new burger

PUT /burger/123 # with data: {name: "chicken king"} to change the name of burger 123
```

For instance, if you had a path with the url

```
GET /burger_list?id=123
```

That would not be considered good practice.

It means you need to think hard about the names you give your resources to make sure the intent is explicit.

**Use HTTP verbs to express your intents**

It basically means using:

- **GET** to read a resource identified by an identifier (id) or a collection of resources
- **PUT** to update a specific resource that you identify by an identifier (id)
- **DELETE** to destroy a specific resource that you identify by an id
- **POST** to create a new resource

Usually, in Rails, those verbs are, by convention, used to map specific actions in your controller.

- **GET** goes to show or index
- **PUT** goes to update
- **DELETE** goes to destroy
- **POST** goes to create

That's why people usually say that if you have actions in your controllers that don't follow that pattern, you're not "RESTful". But in the end, only the routes you expose count. Not really your controller actions. It is a convention of course, and conventions are useful for readability and maintainability.

**You make proper use of HTTP codes to indicate status**

You already know the usual suspects:

- **200** means OK, everything went fine.
- **404** means NOT FOUND, could not find resource
- **401** means UNAUTHORIZED, authentication failed, auth token invalid
- **500** means INTERNAL SERVER ERROR, in other words: kaput

But there are more that you could be using in your responses:

- **201** means CREATED, it means the resource was successfully created
- **403** means FORBIDDEN, you don't have the privileges to access that resource
- ...

You get the picture, it's really about replying with the right HTTP code that represents clearly what happens.

**Answering your questions**

> would that be accurate that it is not RESTful?

From what I see, the first issue is your path.

```
post 'cars/make_list', to: 'cars#make_list'
```

What I understand is that you are retrieving a collection of car makes. Using a POST to retrieve a collection is against REST rules, you should be using a GET instead. That should answer your first question.

> how does that impact my application?

Well, the impact of not being restful in your case is not very big. It's mainly about readability, clarity and maintainability. Separating concerns and putting them in the right place etc... It's not impacting performance, nor is it a dangerous issue. You're just not RESTful and that makes it more complicated to understand your app, in your case of course.

> what should/could I do to resolve that?

Besides the route problem, the other issue is that your action is called make_list and that doesn't follow Rails REST conventions. Rails has a keyword to create RESTful routes:

```
resources :car_makes, only: [:index] # GET /car_makes , get the list of car makes
```

This route expresses your intent much better than the previous one and is now a GET request. You can then use query parameters to filter the results. But it means we need to create a new controller to deal with it.

```
class CarMakesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    makes = params[:year].blank? ? "" : YmmMake.where(ymm_year_id: params[:year]).order(:make)
    render partial: "makes", locals: {car: params[:car], form: params[:form], makes: makes}
  end

  private
  # Strong parameters stuff...
end
```

And of course we also need to change your jquery to make a GET request instead of a POST.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
...  
// when the #year field changes
  $("#car_ymm_year_id").change(function () {
    // ...
    $.get({
        url: '/car_makes',
        data: {
          form: form,
          year: year,
          car: car
        },
        success: function (data) {
          $("#car_ymm_make_id").html(data);
        });
    return false;
  });
  ...
});
```

This is a much better solution, and it doesn't require too much work.

There is an excellent tutorial on REST on [REST API tutorial](http://www.restapitutorial.com/index.html), if you want to know more about the specifics. I don't know much about the small details, mostly what is useful on a day to day basis.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Damn good.  That is what I wanted all along.  I'm not sure I agree with creating extraneous controllers for this purpose, but that is just a point of discussion.  Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, it's a debatable thing. As I said, the most important are your resources, how you access them and what status you return, the name of the controller actions you put behind has nothing to do with being RESTful. Rails conventions recommend the [show index edit update destroy] for RESTful routes but whatever makes your code understandable is fine I guess.

Comment: +1 Got here from your answer to my question. You should write a longer article on REST and Rails, it would be very helpful. And yes, I've read the REST chapter in Rails 4 Way, but this area needs more in depth coverage.