# What's the Rails 4 way to set a single attribute in a RESTful manner?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I know several ways to do this, some simple abusing GET and others quite complicated using PATCH.  The problem is that I have a status flag that needs to be set to various states using simple buttons on the site.

The obvious and very RESTless method is to set up routes like:

```
resources :items do
  get :fail
  get :complete
end
```

That go to controller actions like:

```
def complete
    change_status(3)
end
```

Are accessed by requests like:

```
/items/18/complete
```

And are built by helpers like:

```
link_to image_tag("CheckMarkGreen.png"), item_complete_path(item.id), title: "Flag complete"
```

This method is quick, easy and works well, but it doesn't fit with the RESTful philosophy of Rails 4 routing. All of the more "correct" methods that I have seen involve using forms and POST with hidden parameters to change the method to PATCH.

Is there a better way to do this that is simple, straight forward and correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, the more correct ways to do it involve having a PUT or a PATCH request through a form in the view. But the `link_to` helper and `jquery_ujs` make it easy for you since Rails 3.

```
= link_to image_tag("CheckMarkGreen.png"), item_path(id: item.id, state: :complete), title: "Flag complete", method: :put
```

The `method: :put` basically tells `jquery_ujs` to dynamically replace that link with a form sending data through a PUT request to your server. If javascript is disabled, it will fallback to using GET instead. The only thing you'll see in your rendered page is a `data-method` attribute on the link.

In this case it does a `PUT /items/18` sending `{state: :complete}` as data. You should then handle that in the `update` action of your items controller.

Thoughtbot wrote a very good article on `jquery_ujs` last year:

[A tour or jquery_ujs](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/a-tour-of-rails-jquery-ujs)

I'm not really sure that answers your question, but if I can add anything to it that might help you let me know.

**EDIT additional information**

I wrote an answer on a similar topic that explains a bit more about REST in Rails.

[Making code using JavaScript for dependent selects RESTful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24992310/making-code-using-javascript-for-dependent-selects-restful/25272793#25272793)

Comment: +1 This comes close to an answer, but how do I separate these from the general update case, which supports a real form.  I've seen solutions that use a separate controller, but that is just overkill.

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to do. The way I see it, it's no different from a "general update case". I actually wrote an answer about REST in Rails that you might wanna read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24992310/making-code-using-javascript-for-dependent-selects-restful/25272793#25272793 I personally think that in most cases, a separate controller is the way to go because it separates concerns. But in the end it all comes down to your resources, not your controller action names.

Comment: The link to the query_ujs post is very helpful.  That answers some of my questions about how to make this work seamlessly. I prefer to use REST where possible and appreciate the help.